# common Navigation Button Action another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have made common Navigation bar For all View Controllers. But I need to button action on that which calls I am calling the common navigation bar

```
@objc extension UIViewController {

@objc func setBarButtonItem(titleLabel: String) 
{
let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200 + 4, height: 38))

 let Nextbtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
 Nextbtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
Nextbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NextButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

 view.addSubview(Nextbtn)
 self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: view), animated: true)

   /*
  @objc func NextButtonClicked()
    {
   }*/

 }
 }
```

Calling Controller---> setBackBarButton("hello...")
Button is called if I made button action method on this class. But I want to make button action method func NextButtonClicked() on this calling  Calling Controller class,Or Any approach we can access the button action on this class.

```
 @objc func NextButtonClicked()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just Create `BaseViewController`  Instead extension and allow all ViewControllers to inherit From this BaseViewController

**BaseViewController:**

```
import UIKit
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    typealias CompletionBarButtonClicked = (()-> Void)
    var completionBarItemClicked:CompletionBarButtonClicked?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @objc func setBarButtonItem(titleLabel: String, completion :@escaping CompletionBarButtonClicked)
    {

        self.completionBarItemClicked = completion
        let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200 + 4, height: 38))

        let Nextbtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        Nextbtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        Nextbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NextButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(Nextbtn)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: view), animated: true)

    }

    @objc func NextButtonClicked()
    {
        if let completionHandler = completionBarItemClicked{
            completionHandler()
        }
    }

}
```

**Example ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        self.setBarButtonItem(titleLabel: "test") {

            /// your action There
        }

    }
}
```